# Filters and for loops in Django

Tags: html, django, for-loop, pytorctl

I am sorry if it is an obvious question, I am new to Django and Python. I am working on a small blog application. The following code retrieves all the posts from my database. I do not want to display all of them within the main page. I just need three of them. I am sure it is done using a for loop and some sort of filters according to the documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/

views.py

```
def all(request):
    allPosts = Post.objects.all()
    context = {'Posts': allPosts}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

home.html

```
<div class="sidebar-module">
            <h4>Archive</h4>
            <ol class="list-unstyled">

            {% for singlePost in Posts %}
            <li><a href="#">{{singlePost.title}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ol>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for only 3 posts, there is no need to pull all of the entries, the following will be sufficient:

```
def all(request):
    """To get only three posts use a slice operation."""
    allPosts = Post.objects.all()[:3]
    context = {'Posts': allPosts}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

You can find more in the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets
If you need the results filtered, use the same concept, but apply your filters:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

On the other hand if you are going to use all of them on the same post but just want to restrict only to 3 on a specific part (say a sidebar etc) from the same set, then you could fetch them all as in your original post, and then loops inside the template:

```
<div class="sidebar-module">
    <h4>Archive</h4>
    <ol class="list-unstyled">

    {% for singlePost in Posts|slice:":3" %}
        <li><a href="#">{{singlePost.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
</div>
```

Beware though that the above will result in a new query, if you are experiencing
load problems it would be better, to evaluate your queryset in the view, assign it to a list
and use the evaluated query:

```
def all(request):
    """The bellow evaluates the queryset before it hits the template.
    So slicing in the template (example before) will not result in a new
    Queryset."""
    allPosts = list(Post.objects.all())
    context = {'Posts': allPosts}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

You can find more about evaluation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: Actually, I need all of them for something else.  Should I create two different views. One of them retrieving every post and the other one just three of them. It is a good practice? Thank you

Comment: "Beware though that the above will result in a new query" - not true, Querysets are lazy, so the database isn't hit in either the first or second code blocks until the code in the template. The last is the least efficient as it gets *all* Posts regardless of how many are needed.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I was talking about slicing in the template.